# Saving data without an external .txt file in python

Tags: python, data-storage

For some context: I have a greenhouse that has a sensor that reads in the temperature every minute and adds it to a temp array for an hour. After an hour the average of the array is taken and that value is stored in an hourly array which is used to build and send me an email of a graph every 24 hours.

When I let my system run for 24 hours it is sending the email as intended. However, there are sometimes when I need to make physical changes to the system in which I have to turn the system off to do so. This causes the temp minute and hourly arrays to be lost upon restarting.

The solution I came up with is to store the data in two different .txt files. I know this would work because I am currently doing it to track the minutes elapsed. However, I don't really want to keep adding a bunch of text files to store data. Is there another way?

Comment: Are you asking if other file Types can be used? Or avoiding files all together? If the latter, Why are you trying to avoid files? Even databases persist their data to files. What, precisely, is your functional need?

Comment: Why would you "keep adding a bunch of text files"?  Why would you ever need more than two files - one for minute data (reset every hour) and one for hour data (reset every day)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using txt files or why there are 2 of them. It seems like json is better suited to your system, and you can save it all in one file. Also, why do you lose your files when restarting the system? Pretty much every board out there has drivers for an sd card. Ram is not a great way to permanently store things.

Comment: Hey @xampL welcome to stack overflow. I agree with some points that have been made. Would you be able to describe more what exactly your looking for out of your solution. There would have to be some sort of storage for data persistence.

Comment: @jasonharper - What is the OP wants history? Your method doesn't save any. I think that's what they meant by "bunch of textfiles" ... 2 for every day. Apparently, lumping it all into a json structure is an elusive concept.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy No doubt clumping data into JSON would probably be best across the board if he wants data history. Would also just help with data persistence across the board you can just load a single JSON with current date and continue from there basically. It simplifies it across the board.

Comment: @SomeSimpleton Thank you for the advice regarding my Raspberry Pi project. I intend to have only one txt file per variable, there will never be repeat txt files as I can reset them. While I mentioned "a bunch of txt files," my goal is a simpler, more reusable data storage method. With the addition of txt files for minute and hourly data, I'll have a total of 3 txt files, including the existing one that tracks elapsed minutes. I aim to achieve more accessible and efficient data storage, although I'm unfamiliar with jsons, I'm open to exploring this option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @xampL If that is the case then JSON is your best bet. I dont recommend splitting your data between multiple files just for simplicities sake I would say store each days data in one JSON as it would be a lot simpler to do it that way and when you load in the data for one day you can load it in all at once. This also would help for logging data over time you can just go back and find a specific day and then look through the JSON file to see the history. OneMadGypsy provided a fantastic example below so I would say look at that first.

Comment: My suggestion would be store the temperature and the time it was measured in a `sqlite` database. Support for `sqlite` is built into Python so nothing needs installing. Then your acquisition program just adds the temperatures whenever it runs. You then run a daily/nightly report which picks up the values since midnight, or from last 24 hours, and plots them. When done, you can delete eveything older than 24 hours to prevent the database getting excessively large. See https://pymotw.com/3/sqlite3/index.html

Comment: You've gone very quiet. How did you get on with the suggestions you received?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating text files for each individual variable, you can simply store the information as `json` and load it as a `dict`.

```
import json
from   datetime import datetime as dt
from   random   import randint


#represents your temperature function
def get_ftemp() -> int:
    return randint(-20,120)


#take readings and save data
def set_sample() -> None:
    with open('sensors.json', 'w') as file:
    
        #sensor data for this sample
        sample = dict(
            timestamp = dt.timestamp(dt.now()),
            temp      = get_ftemp()
        )
    
        #overwrite file with updated sample
        file.write(json.dumps(sample))
    
    
def get_sample() -> dict:
    sample = {}
    
    #get sample as dict
    with open('sensors.json', 'r') as file:
        sample = json.loads(file.read())
        
    return sample
```

If you wanted to be able to gather statistical data, over an extended period of time, you can expand on the above and do something similar to the below.

```py
import json
from   datetime import datetime as dt
from   random   import randint


LONG_FORMAT = '%I:%M:%S.%f %A, %B %d, %Y'
TIME_FORMAT = '%I:%M:%S.%f'
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

#represents your temperature function
def get_ftemp():
    return randint(-20,120)

#take readings and save data
def sample() -> list:
    readings = []
    
    with open('sensors.json', 'r+') as file: 
        #get json if file is not empty
        if text := file.read(): 
            readings = json.loads(text)
            
        #sensor data for this reading
        sample = dict(
            timestamp = dt.timestamp(dt.now()),
            temp      = get_ftemp()
        )
        
        #update readings
        readings.append(sample)
    
        #overwrite file with updated readings
        file.seek(0)
        file.truncate()
        file.write(json.dumps(readings))
    
    return readings

#get readings, reformat where necessary
def readings(fmt:str):
    readings = []
    
    with open('sensors.json', 'r') as file: 
        #get json if file is not empty
        if text := file.read(): 
            readings = json.loads(text)
            
    for entry in readings:
        date = dt.fromtimestamp(entry['timestamp'])
        date = dt.strftime(date, fmt)
        del entry['timestamp']

        #yield reformatted date and "rest"
        yield date, *entry.values()
    
#represents statistical analysis
def print_range(m:int, M:int, fmt:str) -> None:
    for date, temp in readings(fmt):
        if m <= temp <= M:
            print(temp, date)


print_range(60, 120, LONG_FORMAT)
```

Keep in mind that the json method has an issue. Every time you store a sample, the entire json file is loaded, the sample is appended to the return value, and the entire file is rewritten with the new data. There will definitely be some point where you should clear the json. One improvement to my script would be to keep an instance of `readings` alive at all times. This way you can cut `read()` down to one initial call, and just `write()` when necessary. The only way around this is to use a "real database", meaning a system that does not have to load in it's entirety to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use `sqlite` to store your readings. It is a well-loved and well-tested technique and has lots of community support. It is *"server-less"* which means you do not have to start any big database management processes, instead it is all contained in a single file and its Python interface which is built into Python's standard library - so nothing to install. There is a good write-up of it [here](https://pymotw.com/3/sqlite3/index.html).

The benefits of using `sqlite` are:

- just a single file for the whole database,
- simple, yet powerful interface used in many iOS apps by Apple, and in many desktop apps such as for Firefox's bookmarks
- accessible from command-line as well as via Python, so you can check readings, remove old  readings from the command-line
- can be created *"in-memory"* or on disk, as you see fit - some folk seem excessively concerned about SD card wear on Raspberry Pi, so create in memory with single change at any time, see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)
- can be easily read into Python, or Pandas and used with `matplotlib` or other Python ecosystem tools

I am no expert at all on `sqlite`, but can show you enough material to get you started. So, I am suggesting creating a database with one table called `readings` and a UTC timestamp for each reading. If you don't supply a timestamp, the database will add the current time for you - simple! Here's the SQL to create the schema, I saved it as `schema.sql`:

```
-- schema.sql
-- Schema for "Logger" application

CREATE TABLE readings (
    timestamp   TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    reading     NUMERIC  NOT NULL);
```

You can run it from the shell to initialise the database (called `logger.db`) like this:

```
sqlite3 -init schema.sql logger.db
```

Or you can create it from Python and write some dummy readings into it as though you had been acquiring data for the last 30 hours at 10 minute intervals like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time
import random
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

dbFilename     = 'logger.db'
schemaFilename = 'schema.sql'

# Check if db exist
newDb = not os.path.exists(dbFilename)

with sqlite3.connect(dbFilename) as conn:
    if newDb:
        # Create schema:
        # You can do same thing from command-line with:
        #   sqlite3 -init schema.sql logger.db
        print('Create schema')
        with open(schemaFilename, 'rt') as f:
            schema = f.read()
        conn.executescript(schema)

        # Populate database with some synthetic data
        # https://github.com/royalosyin/Practice-SQL-with-SQLite-and-Jupyter-Notebook/blob/master/ex13-Using%20SQLite%20as%20a%20Time%20Series%20Database.ipynb
        # H: start this many hours ago
        # M: minutes between readings
        H, M = 30, 10
        print(f'Inserting sample data starting {H} hours ago at {M} minute intervals')
        start = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=H)
        for t in range(0, H * 60, M):
           sampleTimestamp = start + timedelta(minutes=t)
           sampleValue     = random.randrange(10,30)
           print(f'{sampleTimestamp.isoformat()}: {sampleValue}')
           conn.execute(f'''INSERT INTO readings(timestamp, reading) VALUES 
                            ('{sampleTimestamp}', '{sampleValue}')''')

        # Commit all our sample values
        conn.commit()
```

---

Now you can see all the readings in the database from the command-line like this:

```
sqlite3 -column -header logger.db "select * from readings"

timestamp                         reading
--------------------------------  -------
2023-08-09 10:26:13.741923+00:00  28     
2023-08-09 10:36:13.741923+00:00  10     
2023-08-09 10:46:13.741923+00:00  11     
2023-08-09 10:56:13.741923+00:00  23     
2023-08-09 11:06:13.741923+00:00  23     
2023-08-09 11:16:13.741923+00:00  11     
2023-08-09 11:26:13.741923+00:00  13     
2023-08-09 11:36:13.741923+00:00  29 
...
...
```

---

Let's look at the readings from the last 60 minutes:

```
sqlite3 -column -header logger.db 'select * from readings WHERE (timestamp >= datetime("now","-60 minutes"))'
```

---

Let's delete readings older than 36 hours to be sure the database doesn't grow too large:

```
sqlite3 logger.db 'DELETE FROM readings WHERE (timestamp <= datetime("now","-36 hour"))'
```

---

Insert a reading with default, current timestamp from the command-line:

```
sqlite3 logger.db "INSERT INTO readings (reading) VALUES (20.4)"
```

---

Insert a reading with non-default timestamp:

```
sqlite3 logger.db "INSERT INTO readings (reading, timestamp) VALUES (21.6, '2023-08-10 17:33:00')"
```

---

Let's say you live in UK like me, so you would be concerned about frost and the minimum temperature:

```
sqlite3 logger.db "select min(reading) from readings;"
```

Let's say you live in Spain, and are maybe more concerned with the peak temperature:

```
sqlite3 logger.db "select max(reading) from readings;"
```

---

Let's say you want to convert your database to a CSV and Email it to yourself before truncating it to the last 36 hours... that's easy:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv logger.db "select * from readings;" > readings.csv
```

---

Then you can plot the readings using `matplotlib` like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

dbFilename     = 'logger.db'

with sqlite3.connect(dbFilename) as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM readings", conn)
    df.set_index("timestamp", inplace = True)
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True, format='ISO8601')
    df.plot(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want smoothing or averaging, you could certainly add that in here, at the plotting stage.

---

If you want to show your plot in a web-browser, you can save the plot as an *"in-memory"* PNG and return that image to browser like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73797701/2836621) example. You just add three lines at the end of the code above.

---

Note that, although I have just illustrated techniques for adding and reading values using the command-line, all those techniques can be done in Python in an exactly analogous fashion and you can see them in the Python script above that initialises a dummy database.

Note also you can do your averaging and sorting/ordering of your values either with `SQL` or by grabbing all the values in Python and doing the maths yourself - whichever is easiest.

---

As I said, I am no expert **at all** on `sqlite`, so there may be some *"sub-optimal"* things in my code, but they can be addressed by further questions tagged [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite). I understand it is best practice to store all times in UTC and then adjust to local time for presentation - but I may be wrong. It *may* be better to add an index to the database for faster retrieval and storage, but I don't think performance is an issue if you are storing readings once a minute for just a few days. if any `sqlite` experts have any thoughts, I am here to learn and be corrected.