# How to serve concurrent matplotlib figures as images in an HTTP API?

Tags: python, matplotlib, concurrency, python-imaging-library, fastapi

I use `FastAPI` and `Uvicorn` to run an HTTP server.

This server serves images generated from `Matplotlib` figures, using also `Image` from `PIL`:

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from io import BytesIO
    
    fig = fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(SIZE_X, SIZE_Y))
    # Adding elements on figure...
    fig_buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(fig_buf, ax=ax, format='png')
    fig_buf.seek(0)
    fig_img = Image.open(fig_buf)
```

It works well, but when serving multiple HTTP requests in the same time, I get the following error: `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`.

To fix this, I've tried to add `matplotlib.use('AGG')` to use a non-interactive backend, but it doesn't work: I have no more errors but only one of the concurrent figures is well served. The other ones are almost blanks.

Any idea?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73754985/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Maybe try like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/73797701/2836621